# Compressing or stop rendering of JS files from SharePoint on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, optimization

I have costumer who is complaining about massive data traffic on their mobile devices when they enter their website from their cellphones or tablets.

When we made the site in the beginning, we made sure to get rid of every placeholder not necessary etc. What we completely left out was the Javacript files which SharePoint uses for Ribbon, Editmode etc.

We developed a control to stop rendering of controls encapsulated by it when on the mobile device platform. We thought about this long and hard whether or not to use it as well on the javascripts, but came to the conclusion that we cannot stop the loading of core.js, ribbon.js, init.js and debug.js as some parts of the website requires these files to be present to use them.

Ribbon.js we can fully rule out on mobile devices as adding or editing pages, listitems etc on the mobile device should not be possible. But the files like Core.js and Init.js is hard to determine whether or not to rule out as they are crusial for e.g. the Search Center, Social tagging, Social comments etc.

I found [Chris O'Brien's excellent blog](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/01/eliminating-large-js-files-to-optimize.html) on how to compress SharePoints js files to improve loading of your website and we have been using the examples some places on the Desktop edition of the website, but are unclear about how to do so on the Mobile edition.

Have anyone here been in the same situation and throw me some hints or links on how to get around this as we're talking about 15 javascript files in total being loaded (somewhat cached depending on individual mobile settings).

*We've kept our own custom javascript files to a minimum, remotely hosting them if possible to save kb/s traffic.*

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with this company, I am just one of their happy customers.

I would recommend using Aptimize (http://www.aptimize.com/).  Much like the Google Page Speed module does for Apache, Aptimize will compress, minify, etc., all of your page resources at the IIS level.  It takes the headaches out of doing it all manually, especially since manually modifying the SharePoint JS files will lead to an unsupported installation.

We use it on our public web sites and we went from D's and C's on the http://www.webpagetest.org rating scale to all A's.  And from a Google Page Speed Score of 60 to 98.

Comment: Great link that web page test! +1